# How to put both chapter and section name in the header of the page?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I'm working on a one-sided LaTeX document with document class `scrreprt` and I'm using `scrpage2` to customize headers and footers of the pages. At the moment, the respective chapter name is shown in the upper right corner of each page using the following code in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[autooneside]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark{chapter}
\rohead{\headmark}
```

Now I want to change this such that, when a section begins inside a chapter, the `\headmark` should change to the format

> chapter name - section name

on all pages which contain text of this section until the section finishes. If I change `\automark` to `\automark{section}`, then only the section names get displayed but not the chapters names anymore. How can I display both? Is it maybe also possible to put the chapter name in the upper-left corner and the section name in the upper-right corner of each page?

Comment: Would `\rohead{\leftmark{} --- \rightmark}` work?

Comment: @tohecz No, this just displays the chapter name twice on each page. I think this is because I have a one-sided document using the option `autooneside`, therefore there is no difference between `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`.

Comment: Please, compose a full [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), I tried to make one myself and it doesn't show any headers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This does exactly what you need. The only necessary thing was a proper definition of `\sectionmark`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[autooneside]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark{chapter}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\MakeMarkcase {\thesection\hskip .5em\relax#1}}}
\rohead{\ifnum\expandafter\pdfstrcmp\botmark=0 \rightmark\else\leftmark{} --- \rightmark\fi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Cht}
\section{Sct}
\lipsum
\section{SScctt}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

This actually shows `Section -- Chapter`, to show them the other way around, change `\leftmark{} --- \rightmark` to `\rightmark{} --- \leftmark`.

Comment: +1 This works quite well but for pages that start a chapter but do not start a section, the chapter name gets displayed twice. This is ugly. Do you know any way to avoid this?

Comment: @PeterStahl I added the check for equal marks

Comment: I already upvoted your answer -- in the revised version, it should become the accepted one.

Comment: Just now, after a hint by **egreg**, I made a version that is expandable.

Comment: Awesome, your revised solution is far better. The good thing is that the hyphen after the chapter name is not shown if there is no section name to display. The chapter name is now always in the upper-right corner but I think this is better from a design-point-of-view. I will accept this one because I don't have to tell LaTeX it's a two-sided document as in @lockstep's solution. A two-sided setting may lead to problems with other packages later on. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It doesn't seem like `makeatletter` and `makeatother` are needed, since you are not using any commands with `@` ? Compiles fine for me at least.

Comment: Instead of `\thesection\hskip .5em\relax#1` wouldn't `\sectionmarkformat#1` be the KOMA way?

Comment: @cgnieder That's possible, well, I've never used KOMA myself...

Answer (score 9):

A possible solution is to use the `scrreprt` class option `twoside=semi` (with margins like `oneside`, but different `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`).

```
\documentclass[twoside=semi]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{\leftmark}
\rehead{\rightmark}
\lohead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\rightmark}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{bla}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 This exactly produces what I had in mind. It puts the chapter name in the upper-left and the section name in the upper-right corner and nothing gets displayed twice on a single page. Very good. :) Thank you. I will probably accept this solution but will wait for @tohecz to maybe come up with an improvement to his solution.

Comment: Is it possible to put the chapter name in the upper-right corner only for those pages that contain a chapter but no section? At the moment, the chapter name is always in the upper-left corner.

Comment: @PeterStahl It may be possible, but is beyond my abilities. (Also, it would be somewhat incosistent.)

Answer (score 3):

Note, that scrpage2 is depreciated. So here is a suggestion using `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\leftmark\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{ -- \rightmark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cht}
\section{Sct}
\lipsum
\section{SScctt}
\lipsum
\chapter{Next}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to use the outdated package `scrpage2` remove option `autooneside` and use `\automark[section]{chapter}`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\automark[section]{chapter}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ohead{\leftmark\ifstr{\rightmark}{\leftmark}{}{ -- \rightmark}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Cht}
\section{Sct}
\lipsum
\section{SScctt}
\lipsum
\chapter{Next}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```