# How do I insert section and first subsection in the header using scrartcl?

Tags: scrpage2, scrlayer-scrpage

I have a `scartcl` document and I would like to add a header, with the section aligned to the left, and the first subsection on the page aligned to the right. The header should not be in italic. How should I go about doing so?

> **UPDATE**

Based on the answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89287/how-to-put-both-chapter-and-section-name-in-the-header-of-the-page) question and using `scrpage2` I have found the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autooneside]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\automark{section}
\renewcommand\subsectionmark[1]{\markright{\MakeMarkcase {\thesubsection\hskip .5em\relax#1}}}
\rohead{\ifnum\pdfstrcmp\botmark=0 \rightmark\else\leftmark{} --- \rightmark\fi}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I still have three problems:
* The header is in italic
* The section is not aligned on the right
* On the first page the section is displayed twice instead of the section and the subsection.

Can someone help me out?

> SOLUTION: This is what I used from [esdd](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/43317/esdd) answer, thanks!

```
\documentclass[headsepline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  autooneside=false,% use left and right marks with a onesided document
  automark% set \leftmark and \rightmark automatically by \section and \subsection
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}% section on the inner (oneside: right) side
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}% subsection on the outer (oneside: left) side
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}% header upshape instead italic
\cfoot{\thepage}
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\upshape}% header upshape instead italic

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to use `scrlayer-scrpage` with a KOMA-Script class.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  autooneside=false,% use left and right marks with a onesided document
  automark% set \leftmark and \rightmark automatically by \section and \subsection
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}% section on the inner (oneside: right) side
\ohead{\rightmark}% subsection on the outer (oneside: left) side
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}% header upshape instead italic

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum
\subsection{Subsection2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

solves your first and second problem:

[image]

But the third one is still remaining:

[image]

---

To understand the problem:

In your example both `\section` and `\subsection` set a bipartite mark: `\section` sets the right part and the left part to the current section entry. `\subsection` sets the right part to the current subsection and saves the left part unchanged.

There are three kinds of marks: `\botmark` is the last valid mark on a page, `\firstmark` is the first mark set on a page and `\topmark` is the content of `\botmark` from the last page. If there is no new mark on a page `\botmark` and `\firstmark` have the same content as `\topmark`.

Notice that `\leftmark` uses `\botmark` and `\rightmark` uses `\firstmark`.

In your example the first mark on page 1 is set by `\section{Section}` so the right part of this first mark on this page is also "Section".

---

It is possible to remove the left entry in the header if it is the same as the right entry:

```
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{}{\rightmark}}
```

[image]

Or to use `\rightbotmark` if `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are equal:

```
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{\rightbotmark}{\rightmark}}
```

[image]

But then the last subsection on such pages is used. Additionally your problem is not really solved:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
  autooneside=false,
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}{\rightbotmark}{\rightmark}}
\addtokomafont{pagehead}{\upshape}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum
\section{Section2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Now you could use `\righttopmark` on such pages

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{%
  \ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightmark}
    {\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightbotmark}
      {\righttopmark}
      {\rightbotmark}}
    {\rightmark}
  }
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\section{Section1}
\subsection{Subsection1}
\lipsum
\section{Section2}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

to get

[image]

But I think that is not useful.

I would recommend to set only the sections in the header if an article class is used.